# $scope is getting lost while opening a modal on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I am trying to open a modal on ng-click the scipe variables is getting lost.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
 templateUrl: 'partials/create.html', 
 controller: 'AppCreateCtrl', 
 scope: $scope // <-- I added this 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass data using the resolve property like this:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: templateSrv.templateUrl('partials/create.html'),
            controller: modalBootstrap,
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false,
            resolve: {
                data: function () {
                    var result = {};
                    result.scope = $scope;
                    return result;
                }
            }
        });

modalInstance.result.then(
            function (dataPassedFromModalConroller) {
                //this is called when the modal is closed
            },
            function (dataPassedFromModalConroller) { //Dismiss
              //this is called when the modal is dismissed
            }
        );
```

Specify the controller for the modal instance like this (we do this in another file):

```
var modalBootstrap= function ($scope, $modalInstance, data) {
    $scope.modalInstance = $modalInstance;
    $scope.scope = data.userId;
};
modalBootstrap['$inject'] = ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'data'];
```

Your modal template would look something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCreateCtrl">modal content here</div>
```

Comment: Ok after that i will access scope variables like result.myVariable

Comment: No, inside your modal controller you access it like $scope.scope.  The injected data get put on your modal $scope

Comment: $scope.scope.myVariable like this

Comment: Modal controller and the main controller both are same

Comment: yes, if you only want to access one thing on the scope, just pass that along instead of the whole scope

Comment: No, the modal controller would be different.  I'll put an example real quick.

Comment: When I am doind scope:$scipe it creates a new scope as a result the parent scope doean't get inherited

Comment: I have to keep both the controllers same...otherwise it will be an issue

Comment: I'm not sure how or if you can do that.  I've never done it or seen it done before.

Comment: Isn't there way to keep the scopes same

Comment: When you create a new Modal it gets a new controller created so that is why it's scope is different.  You have to inject anything you want into the new controller that is created.  So, no, you can't make them the same $scope

Comment: Then how ro pass the scope cariables of previous controller into new cintroller

Comment: I have to get the controllers same or use the scope of the previous controller into the new controller

Comment: Pass what you need to the modal controller using the resolve property.  If you need to update something on your scope that opened the modal, you can do so when the modal is closed or dismissed.  Is that what you are wanting?